# "Encrypting" files/folders for reading later

Tags: vb.net, .net-4.0

I have a folder. With folders. With files (mainly .pngs).

For learning purposes, I am trying to create an application that will take that folder and "compile" it in one single data file. Like a .bin. The point is, the user can't see or edit the images... easily.

And in the future, my application can open such data file and read the folder's contents, and also display the images found within the folder (using Image.fromFile("pathForTheFile") or something like that).

Is that possible? Is it possible to "encrypt" or "compile" folders/images or even audio into one file and re-read it in a future using VB.NET?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could implement some of the examples in this MSDN article to do what you are looking for: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa719106%28v=vs.71%29.aspx

Comment: But the user is still able to explore the .zip file's contents, I think

Comment: But if the files are encrypted, they would be useless to the user.

Comment: As long as my application can read the contents later, I don't need (nor want) the user to even touch such files.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how much secure you want the mechanism to be.  Just zipping it (like Justin suggested) could still be enough, if you don't write the .zip extension.  But that is *not* secure at all, anybody who still tries to open the "compiled" file with a Zip client will have full access.

You could scramble the binary before rewriting to disc with a simple algorithm, like reversing the order of some bytes.  You would then do the opposite move when reading the file.  It's gonna slow down or maybe stop people from trying to manipulate the file.

If you want real security, you will need some Public Key/Private Key algorithm.  There are some APIs you can use within your app.  A quick Google search gave me some, like http://www.bouncycastle.org/csharp/.

Another way around would be to store your images in a database, and secure your database just like for any other project.

Comment: How do I reverse the order of some bytes?

Comment: If it's for personal use, he could just use some basic symmetric key encryption algorithm by having the VB app prompt for a password when encrypt/decrypting.

Comment: Well, once you have loaded your stream into an array of bytes, you could say, like, every 10 byte, I exchange this byte with the next, or I insert a fake one.  It's a simple loop in the array.